# How to use typedef to an array of function pointers

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, typedef

I have an array of function pointer:

```
int (*collection[2]) (int input1, int input 2) = {&fct1,&fct2}
```

I can get values by calling both functions from the array:

```
*collection[0](1,2);
*collection[1](1,2);
```

Using typedef, I want another way to invoke the array of function pointer. So far, I am doing:

```
typedef int (*alternameName)(int input1, int input 2);
alternateName p = &collection[2];
int result1 = (*p[0])(1,2);
int result2 = (*p[1])(1,2);
printf("results are: %d, %d",result1, result2);
```

My issue is I do not think I properly defined the variable p as I keep getting 0 as my results.

Comment: `alternateName p = &collection[2];` Assuming that this is the same `collection` as above, you take the address of the third element, which does not exist. Try `alternateName p = collection;` or `alternateName p = &collection[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally cleaner to typedef function types, not function pointers. It results in cleaner syntax:

```
typedef int collection_f(int, int);
```

Now you can define `collection`, simply as an array of pointer to `collection_f`.

```
collection_f* collection[2] = {&fct1,&fct2};
```

A typical call syntax would be:

```
collection[0](1,2);
collection[1](1,2);
```

Don't de-reference function pointer prior to calling. Actually, call operator takes a *function pointer* as an operand, not a function. Functions decay to function pointer in all context except `&` operator ... which returns a function pointer.

Next, I'm not sure what:

```
alternateName p = &collection[2];
```

is supposed to mean. I assume that you want `p` to point to the first element of `collection`. Moreover, indexing `p[1]` and `p[2]` looks like out of bound access because accessing collection is only defined for indices 0 and 1.

Now your code could be rewritten can:

```
collection_f** p = collection; // pointer to first element which is a pointer to collection_f
int result1 = p[0](1,2);
int result2 = p[1](1,2);
printf("results are: %d, %d",result1, result2);
```

I hope it fixes the problem.